# Show that if $r$ and $s$ are positive roots to the equation $x^3-cx+d=0$, then $r+s$ is a root of $x^3-cx-d=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $r$ and $s$ are roots of $x^3-cx+d=0$, then

$$r^3-cr+d=s^3-cs+d , $$

for $r \neq s$. Solving the equation for $c$ gives me

$$ c=r^2+rs+s^2$$

Now to find an expression for $d$

$$ r^3-cr+d=0 $$

$$ d=r(c-r^2) $$

Using the expression for $c$ gives me

$$d=sr^2+rs^2$$

Assume $t$ is a root of the second equation

$$t^3-ct+d=0$$

We can represent $c$ and $d$ in terms of $r$ and $s$ which gives us

$$s*r^2+r*s^2=t(t^2-r^2-rs-s^2)$$

Plugging this into wolfram alpha gives us $t=r+s$, which is what we wanted to show. But how can I solve for $t$ algebraically? Or perhaps there is another way to solve this question?

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You have to prove that

$$(r+s)^3-c(r+s)-d=0$$
and you know that, by Vietta in $x^3-cx+d=0$,

$$u+r+s=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x) = x^3-xc-d$ then $p(s)=p(r)=0$.

> This is the part you already made
>  $$s^3-cs =d = r^3-rc$$ so
>  $$ (s-r)(r^2+rs+s^2)= (s-r)c$$ so
>  $$r^2+rs+s^2=c$$

Let $q(x)=x^3-cx+d$.

Now we have \begin{align}q(s+r)&=(s+r)^3-(r+s)c+d\\
&= p(s)+p(r)+3d +3sr(r+s)\\
&= 0+0+3d-3s(c-s^2)\\
&= 3p(s)\\
&=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ be the $3$rd root of the equation $x^3 - cx + d = 0$

So $$t^3 - ct + d = 0 \tag{1}$$

Also $$r + s + t  = 0 \implies t = -(r+s) \tag{2}$$

Substitute the value of $t$ from $(2)$ into $(1)$ to get
$$-(r+s)^3 + c(r+s) + d = 0 \equiv (r+s)^3 - c(r+s) - d = 0$$

Hence the proof.